# Is it possible to type cast data inside an aggregation pipeline on MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

When I need to aggregate things by date using the `aggregate` command on MongoDB, I usually do this:

```
 db.mycollection.aggregate(
 {
        $project: {
            day: {$dayOfMonth: "$date"},
            mon: {$month: "$date"},
            year: {$year: "$date"},
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id : {day: "$day", mon: "$mon", year: "$year"},
            count: {$sum: 1}
        }
    }
 )
```

and eventually concatenate the `day`, `mon`, and `year` fields into a date string in the application. For many reasons though, sometimes I want to concatenate the fields before leaving the database, so I initially tried:

```
 db.mycollection.aggregate(
 {
        $project: {
            day: {$dayOfMonth: "$date"},
            mon: {$month: "$date"},
            year: {$year: "$date"},
        }
    },
    $project: {
            datestr: {
                $concat : ["$year", "-", "$month", "-", "$day"]
            }
        }
    },

    {
        $group: {
            _id : {day: "$day", mon: "$mon", year: "$year"},
            count: {$sum: 1}
        }
    }
 )
```

This won't work because `$concat` expects strings and `day`, `mon` and `year` are integers. So, my question is: can I type cast a field with the `$project` operation?

Comment: Great question. Where did you get the inspiration from :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes**, you can use `$substr` for casting a number to a string. Your missing link would look like:

```
{
    $project: {
        day_s:  { $substr: [ "$day",   0, 2 ] }, 
        mon_s:  { $substr: [ "$month", 0, 2 ] }, 
        year_s: { $substr: [ "$year",  0, 4 ] }
    }
}
```

Comment: Learn something new everyday. That really should be documented and it isn't. Kudos to you for knowing and answering.

Comment: This was my initial source of knowledge: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/LsDR8sSxt40

Comment: This makes only sense if you know the number of digits in advance.