# Group by query in a nested document

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Document structure:

**COLLECTION:** myCollection

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("578818ba8872933f6452c5b5"),
    "user" : ObjectId("578818ba8872933f6452c5b5") ,
    "entries" : {
        "items" : [ 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("578819018872933f6452c5ba")
                "date" : ISODate("2016-07-14T22:57:58.715Z"),
                "values" : [ 
                    { "type" : A, "value" : 4 }, 
                    { "type" : B, "value" : 3 },  
                        ...
                ]
            }, 
            ...
        ]
    }
}
```

**Expected result**

- Group by date (day wise, ignore the time part)
- Average value for each type

  ```
  { 
     "_id" : "2016-07-14",
     "values" : [
                  { "type" : "A", "avgValue" : 3.2 },
                  { "type" : "B", "avgValue" : 4.2 },
                  ...
                ]
  }
  ```

**Tried this but did not help**

```
db.getCollection('myCollection').aggregate(
    [
        {
            "$match" : { 
                        "user" : ObjectId("578818ba8872933f6452c5b5") ,
                        "entries.items.date" : {"$gte" : new ISODate("2016-07-11T00:00:00.715Z"),"$lt" : new ISODate("2016-07-18T00:00:00.715Z")}
                     }
        },
        { "$unwind" : "entires.items"},
        { "$unwind" : "$entries.items.values"},
        {
            "$group" :  { "_id" : { '$year' : '$entries.items.date','$month' : '$entries.items.date','$day' : '$entries.items.date' },
                           "values" :   [{ "type": "$entries.items.values.type",
                                           "avgValue" : { "$avg" : "$entries.items.values.value"}
                                          }
                                       ]
                        }
        }
    ]
)
```

**What is the correct way of achieving this result?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make 2 groups, one for calculating average per type & date, another for pushing type & average value to an array and group these by date :

In `aggregate.js` :

```
var ret = db.device.aggregate(
    [{
        "$match": {
            "user": ObjectId("578818ba8872933f6452c5b5"),
            "entries.items.date": {
                "$gte": new ISODate("2016-07-11T00:00:00.715Z"),
                "$lt": new ISODate("2016-07-18T00:00:00.715Z")
            }
        }
    }, {
        "$unwind": "$entries.items"
    }, {
        "$unwind": "$entries.items.values"
    }, {
        $project: {
            user: 1,
            entries: 1,
            day: {
                year: {
                    $year: "$entries.items.date"
                },
                month: {
                    $month: "$entries.items.date"
                },
                day: {
                    $dayOfMonth: "$entries.items.date"
                }
            }
        }
    }, {
        $project: {
            user: 1,
            entries: 1,
            day: {
                $concat: [{
                        $substr: ["$day.year", 0, 4]
                    },
                    "-", {
                        $substr: ["$day.month", 0, 2]
                    },
                    "-", {
                        $substr: ["$day.day", 0, 2]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }, {
        $group: {
            "_id": {
                "date": "$day",
                "type": "$entries.items.values.type"
            },
            "avgValue": {
                "$avg": "$entries.items.values.value"
            }
        }
    }, {
        $group: {
            "_id": "$_id.date",
            "values": {
                "$push": {
                    "type": "$_id.type",
                    "avgValue": "$avgValue"
                }
            }
        }
    }]
).toArray();

printjson(ret);
```

Test it with :

```
mongo --quiet 127.0.0.1/yourDB aggregate.js
```

I used [two projections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21693349/analog-for-group-concat-in-sql) before the grouping because I didn't get your grouping `_id` working on my system :

```
'$year' : '$entries.items.date','$month' : '$entries.items.date','$day' : '$entries.items.date'
```

I dont know if it comes from my mongo version 2.6

Result gives something like this :

```
[
    {
        "_id" : "2016-7-14",
        "values" : [
            {
                "type" : "B",
                "avgValue" : 4.5
            },
            {
                "type" : "A",
                "avgValue" : 6
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Although your answer works (Thats why I up voted it and accepted it), one grouping and project can be avoided.

After two unwinds, in group by form id using date and type, although result doc structure will be slightly different, result is still the same

Comment: how did you use only one grouping ? I dont see how you can combine $push & $avg in one grouping field